# Neo4j 1.8 M02: Maven compilation error with "cannot find symbol"

Tags: maven, maven-3, neo4j

I just download neo4j-1.8-M02 source file from 22 May 2012 and found that the pom.xml is different from 2 weeks ago. And now, I got the following error.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
J.T.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler- plugin:2.3.2:compile (compile-neo4j-kernel) on project neo4j-kernel: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/pt/Downloads/neo4j-community-081282a/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/helpers/Specifications.java:[54,15] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method and(java.lang.Iterable<java.lang.Object>)
[ERROR] location: class org.neo4j.helpers.Specifications
[ERROR] /home/pt/Downloads/neo4j-community-081282a/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/helpers/Specifications.java:[64,15] cannot find symbol
```

---

pom.xml

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-compile</id>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
          <includes>
            <include>org/neo4j/kernel/impl/annotations/**</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>compile-neo4j-kernel</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

....

```
import org.neo4j.helpers.Service;


              <group>
                <title>Helpers</title>
                <packages>org.neo4j.helpers:org.neo4j.helpers.*</packages>
              </group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you building with OpenJDK? We have problems with an OpenJDK bug in there, so please try OracleJDK to compile. Does that work better?

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you very much for the answer. I faced this problem during trying to install neo4j at home while i don't have this problem in the office because of difference JDK. Thank you.

Comment: OpenJDK 1.6 SDK (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2) still doesn't compile neo4j, similar error.  The instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Oracle_.28Sun.29_Java_6 were helpful for me switching to Oracle's JDK on Ubuntu.  After switching, `mvn compile` appears to work.

Comment: Great! Also, I think OpenJDK is working now as of https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/350